# Element length and index with simple html dom

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, simple-html-dom, variable-length

I'm using Simple HTML DOM to get a certain element like this:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $d) { 
 echo $d->outertext;
}
```

This will echo all the images. Let's say for example I only need image with index (meaning relative to all images) number 3,7,14 and > 15. Is there a way to do something this complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`find`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find) returns an array so just use the index

```
$imgs =$html->find('img');

$imgs[3];
$imgs[7];
$imgs[14];

for($i=15;$i<count($imgs);$i++){
  $imgs[$i];
}
```

Comment: `$imgs =$html->find('img');

$imgs[3];
$imgs[7];
$imgs[14];

for($i=15;$i<count($imgs);$i++){
  $imgs[$i];
}

foreach($html->find($imgs) as $d) { 
 echo $d->outertext;
}` ..........nothing

Comment: Look at the documentation on how the elements work, the array is an array of objects you have to use whatever mechanism the library uses to get the actual data.

Comment: and does it actually find any imgs? if $imgs ends up being empty you havent found any img tags to begin with.

Comment: This is the website http://www.nu.nl/ There are plenty of images. I can call them using the code in my answer, but implementing your code just doesn't work

Comment: you dont just copy and paste my code, you have to tailor it for your code, and it doesnt just go above your old code, its just showing you how you would access the array. you have to actually use the array elements in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way is to add all the `img` tags to an array, and from there you can extract them according to index number.

Comment: The problem is extraction, how do I do that in an efficient way without repeating the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a `$count` variable and [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array). Declare the count variable before the loop, and declare the array of the required IDs. And in the loop, you can use an if statement to check if the image ID is in the array **or** greater than 15.

```
$count = 1;
$ids = array(3, 7, 14);

foreach($html->find('img') as $d) { 
if(in_array($count, $ids) || $count > 15){

 echo $d->outertext;
 $count++;    

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't return anything

Comment: @Youss: What does `print_r($html->find('img'))` output?

Comment: Well, how do you expect it to work when you have nothing in the array? Does the foreach loop in your question output anything?

Comment: Yes the foreach loop works, I don't know why your code doesnt work but I think it's not "simple html dom" coding